# Moments of a quadratic and quartic exponential

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, gaussian-integral

I am interested in the calculation of an integrals like
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm d x \; e^{-ax^2-bx^4} x^n
\end{equation}
where $n\in\mathbb N$ and $a,b\in\mathbb R^+$. By expanding the quartic term in series, the result reduces to the series of momenta of a Gaussian integral. Is the whole series an analytic function? If so, how can it be computed?

Comment: The series expansion in $b$ has a zero radius of convergence as can be seen by considering the case of $b<0$ (at least for even $n$'s)

Comment: In my case, $b>0$ as specified above, hence I would expect a convergent result. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: The integral converges, but the series expansion in $b$ is asymptotic. A shallow search found this: http://diposit.ub.edu/dspace/bitstream/2445/59765/1/TFG-Garcia-Tormo-Joan.pdf , Might be a useful starting point